# In Futurama, why did the DNA scanner say Prof Farnsworth was Fry's only living relative when he had several others?

Tags: futurama

In "Bender's Game", we learn that Prof. Hubert Farnsworth fathered Mom's son, Igner. In "Near-Death Wish", it's revealed that both the Professor's parents (Ned and Velma Farnsworth) are still alive, and that he has a younger brother, Floyd. Bender even mentions that Floyd had stopped by Planet Express once, looking for Hubert. So Hubert, Floyd, Igner, and either Ned or Velma would be biological relatives of Fry.

Why, then, did the DNA scanner in the pilot episode say that Hubert Farnsworth was Fry's only living relative?

(Note: Hubert's clone / son, Cubert, would be another biological relative, but he was't born yet when the DNA scan was done.)

Comment: I don't have an answer for a lot of those, but Igner is probably 'officially' not recorded as the Prof's son, and Mom has enough political and financial power to prevent his DNA from being tied to his in government databases (if they are even in those databases to begin with).

Comment: One could rationalize that Ned & Velma were legally dead (or at least not "living") in their VR purgatory and Floyd was far enough off the grid to escape notice. Mostly, I think that these characters hadn't been conceived of yet.

Comment: This is futurama were talking about. Not exactly Philip K Dick. It's good because it's funny, not because it's an exquisitely written sci fi.

Comment: Genetically speaking, "one living relative" seems to be a virtual improbability. It would mean that for 1000 years, all of the offspring of Phillip's brother would only have a single survivor? Highly unlikely, which means that the phrase you are relying on isn't possible in-universe or meanss something different in the year 3000

Answer (score 12):

In-universe, it was never addressed. Out of universe, *Bender's Game* was written and aired nearly 9 years — and a few cancellations — after the pilot. While Futurama was great about continuity and references to obscure plot threads from earlier episodes, these things happen.

Comment: Sounds about right to me.

Comment: I don't think "These things happen" applies.   It certainly does for other series, but for Futurama the correct answer is "Continuity should not stand in the way of a good joke."

Comment: @thepop what makes you think this was an instance of ignored continuity instead of forgotten continuity.

Comment: @cde:   What makes you think the other way round?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/LoCte

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/MMK5zga.jpg

Comment: Because those disregard continuity but still reference them.

Answer (score 4):

Ned and Velma can be justified by the fact that they were classified as 'near-death' and thus were locked up in the near-death star.

Igner's father was never explained outside of Bender's Game, and probably wasn't listed on the birth certificate ( or Mom could've not listed information in those databases because she's so rich and powerful)

Floyd was also in an asylum (ned and velma thought Hubert was Floyd and hence the confusion).

The DNA scanner found the closest living relative, presumably to find a place for the defrostee to acclimate with a (somewhat) familiar setting which would have led them to Hubert.